# Webflux with different authentication schemes

Tags: spring, authentication, flux, bearer-token

I just got a project I need to maintain and I need to add support for an extra authentication scheme in a resource server. Something like besides regular `Authentication: Bearer <jwt.token>` to use a custom one: `Authentication: Custom <other.jwt.token>`. Both should work and handled differently.

Yes, I know spring can handle multiple providers, I know I can use a ReactiveAuthenticationManager but I am stuck in how to deal with the `Custom` prefix for the opaque token.

Just to make it clear, I need both to work - and, of course, to be handled differently:

```
GET /
Authorization: Bearer x.y.z
```

and

```
GET /
Authorization: Custom a.b.c
```

If possible, I'd like also to return the list of supported authentication protocols in `WWW-Authorization` header (i.e. `Bearer, Custom`).

Any hints? Googling only points me to regular stuff, with Bearer and whatever I try, spring automatically rejects me with 401 (of course, token is not handled).

Thanks.

Comment: `getHeader("Authorization")`. Check if it starts with `Custom` cut it off. It is really no different as with a BASIC or BEARER header that is done in the exact same way.

Comment: Yes, of course. But my question is where? I couldn't find a reasonable example in spring source code or on web on how to handle multiple such requests.

Comment: Take a look at the sources and how basic and bearer are handled. You can create your own (and register it) to handle your custom one.

Comment: Good point. In fact, I was hoping for an already made example with something like this but your suggestion is good as well. Thanks. I'll do that and post the update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

- I implemented different `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`, one for each protocol I needed. Something like `BearerReactiveAuthenticationManager` and `CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager` and made them `@Components`;
- I also implemented `ServerSecurityContextRepository` and injected both authentication managers from previous point. In the body I had something like:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.bearerReactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(auth)
                    .map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
        } else if (authHeader.startsWith("Custom ")) { {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.customReactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(auth)
                    .map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
        } else {
            log.debug("Could not identify the authentication header");
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
```

And my SecurityConfig bean looked like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final ServerSecurityContextRepository serverSecurityContextRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(ServerSecurityContextRepository serverSecurityContextRepository) {
        this.serverSecurityContextRepository = serverSecurityContextRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .securityContextRepository(serverSecurityContextRepository)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
                .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)))

                .and().authorizeExchange();

       return http.build();
   }
}
```